# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TikaEntityProcessor

Tags: apache-tika

We have Apache Solr 9.2.1 installed but when indexing a binary blob field, Apache Tika 1.28.5 (tika-core-1.28.5.jar and tika-parsers-1.28.5.jar) does not extract the text from the documents, throwing the next error:

```
2023-10-03 16:44:50.199 ERROR (Thread-16) [] o.a.s.h.d.DataImporter Full Import failed => java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to load EntityProcessor implementation for entity:document_binary Processing Document # 1
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:274)
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to load EntityProcessor implementation for entity:document_binary Processing Document # 1
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:274) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.doFullImport(DataImporter.java:424) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.runCmd(DataImporter.java:483) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImporter.lambda$runAsync$0(DataImporter.java:466) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) [?:?]
Caused by: org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException: Unable to load EntityProcessor implementation for entity:document_binary Processing Document # 1
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DataImportHandlerException.wrapAndThrow(DataImportHandlerException.java:69) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.getEntityProcessorWrapper(DocBuilder.java:744) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.getEntityProcessorWrapper(DocBuilder.java:750) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:218) ~[?:?]
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Unable to load TikaEntityProcessor or org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.TikaEntityProcessor
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.loadClass(DocBuilder.java:966) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.getEntityProcessorWrapper(DocBuilder.java:741) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.getEntityProcessorWrapper(DocBuilder.java:750) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:218) ~[?:?]
        ... 4 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TikaEntityProcessor
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:476) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:589) ~[?:?]
        at java.net.FactoryURLClassLoader.loadClass(URLClassLoader.java:904) ~[?:?]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.loadClass(DocBuilder.java:960) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.getEntityProcessorWrapper(DocBuilder.java:741) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.getEntityProcessorWrapper(DocBuilder.java:750) ~[?:?]
        at org.apache.solr.handler.dataimport.DocBuilder.execute(DocBuilder.java:218) ~[?:?]
        ... 4 more
```